# more loaded posts are moved by css

Tags: javascript, css, margin

Picture about my problem:

[image]

When my Load more loads more posts then the new ones get again content style, i have tried to load these posts without load more and it works well. As you can see on the picture, loaded more posts go like that and if i load more posts the it goes crazy

```
<div id="content">
<div class="inner">
$last_post_id=$_GET['last_post_id'];
$action=$_GET['action'];

if($action <> "get")
{

?>
                <!-- Post -->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
var bSuppressScroll = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

    function last_msg_funtion() 
    { 

       var ID=$("div.postsize:last").attr("id");

        $.post("main.php?leht=latest&action=get&last_post_id="+ID,

        function(data){
            if (data != "") {
            $("div.postsize:last").after(data);
            window.bSuppressScroll = false;         
            }
            $('div#last_post_loader').empty();

        });
    };  

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( ( $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) && window.bSuppressScroll == false ){
            last_msg_funtion();
        window.bSuppressScroll = true;
        }
    }); 

});



</script>

<?php
include('include/latest1.php');
echo $list;

}
else
{
include('include/latest.php');  
echo $list2;
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
#content {
            padding: 3em 5em 8em 5em;
            margin-left: 21em;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of using `.after` to `div.postsize:last`, try using `.append` to `div.postsize`

Comment: replace $(**"div.postsize:last"**).after(data); with $(**"#content>.inner"**).after(data);

Comment: tried those but they still get their own content style